# How do I disable the emoji picker in the message input box in get stream?

Tags: getstream-io, getstream-chat

I can't seem to figure out how to disable the EmojiPicker on my GetStream React app. I've read this documentation about how to create a custom EmojiPicker, but I can't seem to figure out how to disable the element entirely: [https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/react/guides/customization/emoji_picker/](https://stackoverflow.com). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [this page](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/react/components/message-input-components/input_ui/#basic-usage), the important part is to provide a `CustomInput` (which can be named differently) to the `Channel`'s `Input` parameter.

Creating a custom input (taken from the docs, but omitting the `EmojiPicker`) can be done like this:

```
const CustomInput = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ImageDropzone>
        <QuotedMessagePreview />
        <UploadsPreview />
        <ChatAutoComplete />
        <FileUploadButton />
        <SendButton />
      </ImageDropzone>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This can then be input into the app tree like this:

```
<Chat client={client}>
  <Channel channel={channel} Input={CustomInput}>
    <MessageList />
    <MessageInput />
  </Channel>
</Chat>
```

The place where this customization is described is [here](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/react/components/message-input-components/input_ui/#ui-customization).